# Error expected expression before struct

Tags: c, file, struct, syntax

The errors that prevent my code from compiling are:

> [Error] expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
>
> [Error] expected expression before 'books'
>
> [Error] too few arguments to function 'fread'

I'm new to C programming and programming altogether. Although I'm used to Pascal. The errors occur in all functions except in the main and void menu. This is only a part of my code.

Please can someone help me in solving these errors this program.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>                 
#include <ctype.h>                   

char catergories[][15]={"Computer","Philosophy","Arts","Literature","Science","History"};
void menu(void);
void addbooks(void);
void deletebooks(void);
void updatebooks(void);
void findbooks(void);
void sellbooks(void);
void viewbooks(void);
int  enterinfo();
int  checkid(int);
void Password();

//list of global files that can be accessed from anywhere in program
FILE *fp,*ft,*fs;

//list of global variable
int s;
char findbook;
char password[10]={"dominique"};

typedef struct
{
    int mm,dd,yy;
}OrderDate;

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char name[35];
    char author[35];
    int quantity;
    float price;
    int count;
    int shelf;
    char *cat;
    struct OrderDate *sold;
}books;

void addbooks(void)    //funtion that add books
{
    system("cls");

    int i;
    struct books;

    printf("\n ******************************************************\n");
    printf("\n \t\t ADD A BOOK");
    printf("\n ******************************************************\n\n");
    printf("\n SELECT THE CATERGORY OF THE BOOK:");
    printf("\n 1. Computer Science, Information & General Works");
    printf("\n 2. Philosophy, Psychology and Religion");
    printf("\n 3. Arts and Recreation");
    printf("\n 4. Literature");
    printf("\n 5. Science");
    printf("\n 6. History and Geography");
    printf("\n 7. Back to main menu\n");
    printf("\n Enter your choice:");
    scanf("%d",&s);

    if(s==7)
    {
        menu() ;
    }

    system("cls");
    fp=fopen("BookRecords.txt","ab+");

    if(enterinfo()==1)
    {
        books.cat=catergories[s-1]; //the error that exists here states expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
        fwrite(&books,sizeof(books),1,fp); //the error that exists here states expected expression before 'books'
        fclose(fp);
        printf("\n The book's information has been saved sucessfully");
        printf("\n Would you like to save more information? (Y/N):");

        if(getch()=='n')
        {
            menu();
        }
    else
        system("cls");
        addbooks();
    }
}
```

Comment: One way to avoid this nightmare in the future is to build and test the program step by step. At least you won't be making the same errors over and over.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0):

```
struct books;
```

`books` is your type name. Like `int` or `char`. Thats why `books.id==d` won't work. You have to declare variable that is type of books. For example:

```
books BooksInMyShop;
```

Now you can use your variable in code ex.:

```
if(BooksInMyShop.id == currentId)
```

---

PS1: When You define:

```
typedef struct
{
 (...)
}books;
```

You dont need to declare variable by `struct books BooksInMyShop;` simple `books BooksInMyShop;` will work now.

PS2: I can see in your code lots of missconceptions. For example "variable" `books` in every function in not shared beetween them. I guess You have to pass one instance of Your `bookstore` to every function or have one static global instance.